# How to distribute budget value to actual rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, outer-join

Budget table contains jobs with loads:

```
create temp table budget (
  job char(20) primary key,
  load numeric(4,1) not null check (load>0 )
  );
insert into budget values ( 'programmer', 3 );
insert into budget values ( 'analyst', 1.5 );
```

Actual table contains actual loads by employees:

```
create temp table actual (
  job char(20),
  employee char(20),
  load numeric(4,1) not null check (load>0 ),
  contractdate date,
  primary key (job, employee)
  );

insert into actual values ( 'programmer', 'John',  1, '2014-01-01' );
-- half time programmer:
insert into actual values ( 'programmer', 'Bill', 0.5, '2014-01-02' ); 

insert into actual values ( 'analyst', 'Aldo', 1, '2014-01-03' );
insert into actual values ( 'analyst', 'Margaret', 1, '2014-01-04' );
```

Result table should show difference between budget and actual jobs so that budget load is 
distributed to employees in contract date order.

If budget load is greater than sum of job loads, separate budget line with  empty employee
should appear.

In data above, 1.5 programmers are missing and 0.5 analysts are more.

Result should be

```
Job        Employee  Budget  Actual  Difference

programmer John      1       1       0
programmer Bill      0.5     0.5     0
programmer           1.5     0       1.5
analyst    Aldo      1       1       0
analyst    Margaret  0.5     1       -0.5
```

How to create such table in modern Postgresql ?
Can rank function with full join used or other idea ?

I tried

```
select
 coalesce(budget.job, actual.job ) as job,
 employee,
 budget.load as budget,
 coalesce(actual.load,0) as actual,
 coalesce(budget.load,0)-coalesce( actual.load,0) as difference
from budget full join actual using (job)
order by 1, contractdate
```

but this does not distribute budget load to employee rows.

I posted this also in pgsql-general mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

The following query gets what you want:

```
select job, employee, budget, actual,
       (budget - cumload) as diff, contractdate
from (select coalesce(b.job, a.job ) as job, a.contractdate,
             a.employee,
             b.load as budget,
             coalesce(a.load,0) as actual,
             sum(a.load) over (partition by a.job order by a.contractdate NULLS last) as cumload
      from budget b join
           (select a.*
            from actual a
            union all
            select b.job, NULL, NULL, NULL
            from budget b
           ) a
           on b.job = a.job
     ) ab
where contractdate is not null or budget > cumload
order by job, contractdate
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3c7eb/15).

Note that this uses `union all` to bring in the extra rows needed for the query.  You wanted to do this with a `full outer join`, but that doesn't generate extra rows when the `join` conditions are met.

Also, the logic that you are looking for requires a cumulative sum, which Postgres happily provides.

Comment: Thank you. Budget column dow not change in your answer for job and thus this is wrong: Total sum on budget column must be equal to total budget in budget table. Desired result in question shows distributed budget for job: If actual is present in row, budget should be never greater than actual: budget should distributed to actual until it becomes 0 or new row with unfilled budget only should appear. Difference column is always difference between two previous columns. How to fix this ?